# Homotopy between a closed geodesic and a closed curve.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory, geodesic

Let $M^{n}$ a Riemannian manifold orientable with positive curvature and even dimension. Let $\gamma$ a closed geodesic. Prove that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a closed curve whose lenght is strictly less than $\gamma$. I would any tips for solve this problem, because , i honestly i do know which tool use.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need some assumptions about compactness or completeness of $M$. The key will be to produce a deformation of $\gamma$ that, due to some fact about positive curvature, has shorter length. What tools describe deformations of geodesics? (Hint: starts with "J" and ends with "acobi field")

Comment: @Neal i will think according to your tips. Thanks.

Comment: @Neal: No need for compactness/completeness. This is just a local issue in a small neighborhood of $\gamma$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Good call.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a parallel translation $P : T_pM\rightarrow T_pM$ along a
closed geodesic $\gamma$ where $\gamma (0)=\gamma (l)=p$

Since $M$ is orientable, then $P$ is orientation preserving isometry
on $T_pM$ so that it has a fixed point $v$. When
$\gamma(t,s)=\exp_{\gamma (t)}\ sV(t)$ where $V$ is a parallel field
s.t. $V(0)=v$, then ${\rm length}\ \gamma(t,s)<{\rm length}\
\gamma(t,0)$ for $s>0$, since $M$ has a positive curvature.

Answer (score -1):

Either I didn't understand you, or the statement is false. There exist non- simply connected positively curved manifolds of even dimension (e.g. product of two lens spaces). So choose any non-trivial class in fundamental group and consider the shortest (smooth) loop in this class by minimizing the length functional. It will be geodesic.

Comment: Your example does not have strictly positive curvature. It is a standard result that found e.g. in do Carmo's book that oriented even dimensional positively curved manifolds are simply connected. Your example has nonnegative curvature only.